# Как автоматизировать golang на автозапуск

Tags: sql, oracle, golang

Как мне сделать так, чтобы мой билд запускался автоматически каждого 1- го числа каждого месяца, при этом:
менялась дата в `packno` за предыдущий месяц. То есть напримере запуск 1 августа, а `packno` за 07 месяц.

```
rows, err := db.Query("select section_id, modified_by from enrollment where packno between '220701001' and '220731011'")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error running query")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  defer rows.Close()

  var section_id string
  var modified_by string
  file, err := os.Create("text.txt")
  if err != nil {
    return
  }
  
  for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&section_id, &modified_by)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
    }
    file.WriteString("\n \t" + section_id + modified_by)
    
  }


  defer file.Close()
  fmt.Println("FILE RECORDED")
```

Comment: Я подозреваю, что вам не билд переделывать надо, а просто подсунуть нужную строчку в запрос в зависимости от текущей даты

Comment: Да, так и надо, а как это сделать? Воспользоваться пакетом Time?  А автозапуск через планировщик?